# How can I run my systemd service with a `SCHED_DEADLINE` scheduling policy?

Tags: linux, scheduling, systemd, systemctl, sched-deadline

I want to run my systemd service with a `SCHED_DEADLINE` scheduling policy.

I already have this with

```
chrt -d --sched-runtime 1000000 --sched-deadline 5000000 --sched-period 5000000 -p 0 <PID>
```

However this is a service and I don't want to apply this command manually.

I found that in my service config I can change `CPUSchedulingPolicy` and `CPUSchedulingPriority`, but according to [this manual](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html) the value

> Takes one of other, batch, idle, fifo or rr

Plus I need to define runtime, deadline, period values somewhere.
So, is there any way to do that properly? I tried to put the `chrt` command in the `ExecStart` section, however thats doesn't work and I think it's not the best way

Comment: I found this [github issue](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/10034). So is there any other way to do that properly?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because From the tag: systemd questions should be for *programming questions* using systemd or its libraries. Questions about *configuring the daemon* (including writing unit files) are better directed to Unix & Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com. Please delete this.